# Display drop down selected option in php

Tags: php, html

I want to display a simple html drop down box and selected value want to print.

```
<select name="v">
    <option value="fkt">Flipkart</option>
    <option value="snd">Snapdeal</option>
</select>
```

When the `flipkart` is selected `php echo` should print "Flipkart".
When the `snapdeal` is selected `php echo` should print "Snapdeal".

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or search anything?

Comment: You can't accomplish this with `PHP` because the DOM elements are already loaded. You should look at JavaScript.

Comment: value="<?php    echo $rows -> v;?>" try this

Comment: You can do it in using onchange event ,taking this.value through onchange event  .

Comment: where you want to show?

Comment: can i show this on page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="v" class='Product'>
    <option value="fkt">Flipkart</option>
    <option value="snd">Snapdeal</option>
</select>

<textarea class='showDescription'></textarea> <br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
          $('.Product').change(function(){
                 var Product = $('.Product').val();
                 $(".showDescription").val(Product);
          });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: how can i display the selected option value on the form.

Comment: If you will paste your full code in your question. I can look into it. Please edit your question with full code. @RashmiSonke

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".showDescriptionTextbox").val($(".Product").val());//to initialize
  $(".showDescriptionDiv").text($(".Product").val());//to initialize
  $(".Product").change(function(){
    $(".showDescriptionTextbox").val($(".Product").val());
    $(".showDescriptionDiv").text($(".Product").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="v" class="Product" id="dropdown">
    <option value="fkt">Flipkart</option>
    <option value="snd">Snapdeal</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
value in textarea: <input type="text" class="showDescriptionTextbox">
<div>
or you can display value in div: <span class="showDescriptionDiv"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for it.

```js
  

    function shop(shop)
    {
         
        $("#show").val(shop);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select   onchange="shop(this.value)">
    <option value="Flipkart">Flipkart</option>
    <option value="Snapdeal">Snapdeal</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>

<input type="text" id='show'>
```

Comment: While copying code from my answer, you forgot to remove `class='Product'` from `<select></select>` dropdown.

Comment: Yes you are right ,i have used my own logic to do it. @Nana Partykar

Comment: **Well Edited.** But, I didn't said a single word about logic @Sradha