# Where to add JavaScript code that needed jQuery file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've founded this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34289038/8190366) but I don't know where to add this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".showDescriptionTextbox").val($(".Product").val());//to initialize
  $(".showDescriptionDiv").text($(".Product").val());//to initialize
  $(".Product").change(function(){
    $(".showDescriptionTextbox").val($(".Product").val());
    $(".showDescriptionDiv").text($(".Product").val());
  });
});
```

I've file `jquery-1.11.3.min.js`, `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`.

Should I edit one of both file with above code? Please give me a hint.

I want to execute query SQL by clicking the select option that I know it's just possible using jquery/ajax/js, but I'm still newbie.

Comment: it should be inside a <script> tag. if you want to learn jquery you can check out w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ this can help you.

Comment: use just _jquery-1.11.3.min.js_ and create another file 'script.js' and add the code inside it and call the both in your HTML page.

Comment: @Redan I've seen another source code that i just need to add seperate javascript code in another file, and just call that file without add <script> tag,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I've file jquery-1.11.3.min.js, jquery-1.10.2.min.js.` Both are jquery library file with different version. Only one should be included.

In your case the code snippet which you have shared can be included in a separate js file. Like this

`nameOfYourJSFile.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".showDescriptionTextbox").val($(".Product").val());//to initialize
  $(".showDescriptionDiv").text($(".Product").val());//to initialize
  $(".Product").change(function(){
    $(".showDescriptionTextbox").val($(".Product").val());
    $(".showDescriptionDiv").text($(".Product").val());
  });
});
```

Include the file in your main html file. Add the scripts near the bottom of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="nameOfYourJSScript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/jNVseeLLAGSTgYNsb2Rj?p=preview)

If the file is included in the bottom , there is no need to use `document.ready` function

Answer (score 0):

Add your code BELOW the `<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

So, JQuery will be loaded and can be used

Comment: i think you don't understand what i want, i need to know where should i put above code, not just to loaded jquery file

Comment: I think you don't understand my answer and I don't know how I can be more explicit.

Comment: read carefully what i want,
if you just explain about <script> its really not helpful me or the others who find this, the point is how to add above code, not to *__LOADED__* some file

Comment: You asked where to put your code... If you use your code ABOVE `<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>` the jquery library won't be loaded when attempting to use it...